# Why can I not refresh my Snowflake extracts on Tableau server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, extract, tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have seen this question asked before concerning extracting Snowflake data on Tableau Server(v 2020.3 with 2020.3 desktop version), however so far none of the solutions have solved the issue.

The error I am seeing is this job failed on Feb 16, 2021, 3:16 PM after running for 1.9 min because of: com.tableausoftware.nativeapi.exceptions.ConnectivityException: [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) REST request for URL[my URL] failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=7 msg='Couldn't connect to server' osCode=10060 osMsg='Unknown error'.

I have asked the Tableau and Snowflake admins about network settings etc. and am told everything is set up correctly. However, there is another group within the company who is following the same process, and their extract refreshes are working fine. Could it be a set up on AWS? a Snowflake issue? a network proxy? the Tableau server version? I am using Server 2020.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my past experience, this has almost always been a networking-related issue such as proxy configuration. [This function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_whitelist.html) gives the list of endpoints that will need to be whitelisted or bypassed in any firewall, proxy, security policy, etc. One of the endpoints will be an internal S3 bucket so make sure they are all included. The networking team should be able to trace traffic (i.e., the packet flow).

Additionally, you could try to look for more clues in logs (Tableau or [Snowflake ODBC](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors)) which might show some connectivity errors.  Further troubleshooting could be with [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) or comparing the environmental differences between your team and the "group" you mention whose extracts are successful.

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, with the network admins and Snowflake and Tableau admins we were able to solve with the following steps:

In Registry Editor, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE--> SOFTWARE-->Snowflake-->Driver and  right click "add -- New string value".  name will be "PROXY" and value will be <your company name>.cnb:80.  Add another string value with Name = "Disable OSCP Check" and value = "true".
Repeat step 1  in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE--> SOFTWARE-->OSBC.INSTI.INI-->SnowflakeDSIIDriver.
Repeat steps 1 and 2 in  HKEY_CURRENT_USER. 
Don't add proxy settings in Tableau desktop Custom Driver Params.

Comment: Understood and thanks for sharing.  It sounds like you added proxy configuration settings directly to the driver itself in the Windows registry. That is definitely an option I've used in the past that works as it can be used with Tableau's direct connection to Snowflake.  Interesting that Tableau Desktop's custom driver parameters didn't work for you - that might be something for Tableau to take back to their team.