# Error while connecting tableau to snowflake using username and password

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

[image][***See Screenshot***]

Hi, Connecting Snowflake as data source in Tableau and
I am using correct username and password but still getting the below error (refer to screenshot)

Comment: Are you sure the DNS is able to resolve the hostname of the account? Is it under the form **<account>.<region>.snowflakecomputing.com** ? <region> is not needed if you use regionless URL.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is very clear: "Couldn't resolve host name". Can you ping the hostname from the client machine?

This is a networking issue, not Snowflake issue, or credentials issue.

Comment: https://pd02959.ap-south-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/console#

Comment: above is the url ....see if you can help me out.

Comment: Please remove "/console#" and try again.

Also, it might be due to the networking issue mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231742/why-can-i-not-refresh-my-snowflake-extracts-on-tableau-server

Comment: I can see the login page by going to https://pd02959.ap-south-1.aws.snowflakecomputing.com/, can you open it in your browser and land on the login page?

Comment: yes, I can access to login page using the above url.

Comment: Are you running inside a VM, or on a host?

Comment: yes, I'm running inside a VM

Comment: Can you open that url from within the VM? How did you setup the network bridge between the the host and guest?